# Connecting to a Cassandra Database

Tags: cassandra

I am new to Cassandra. I am now working on Ubuntu and the latest Cassandra. I am using Java 1.7 on a PC. I created the installation on a PC without any cloud or server network (replication was one). I can use CQL ok but when I am trying in Java the code fails.

Here is the code:

```
    Cluster cluster;
    Session session;
    cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
    session = cluster.connect("casslinks");

    if (!tableExists(linktable, session))
    {
        createCassTable(linktable, session);
    }

    for (String url: urls) {
        insertCassUrl(url, crawledUrl, session, linktable);
    }
```

Here is the error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" 
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<clinit>(Cluster.java:65)
at com.example.GetSoogrData.insertUrls(GetSoogrData.java:596)
at com.example.GetSoogrData.main(GetSoogrData.java:1112)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

I used the debugger and saw the session line failed. I assume the IP address is wrong. I am unsure how to test for the correct IP address or how to define the session variable to it will correctly connect.

I have been using mongo db and 127.0.0.1 works for that.

Has anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably running your code with missing dependencies.
Datastax java driver requires few addidional jars, SLF4J libraries being one of them for which exception is thrown.

Look here to see what jars you need:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.0/java-driver/reference/settingUpJavaProgEnv_r.html

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.0/common/drivers/introduction/driverDependencies_r.html